# How to add a comment on my deleted post?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

I posted an answer (here on Meta Stack Overflow) to some question and a moderator deleted it, then he sent me a comment on why he deleted my answer.

I want to reply on his comment but instead of "Add Comment" button, I see

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

How can I communicate with this moderator to make sure of the reason for deletion ?

How is it possible that I cannot comment on my post while others can ?

Comment: _How is it possible that I cannot comment on my post while others can ?_ I don't think others can comment on your deleted posts while it's deleted either.

Comment: @jakekimds Moderators can.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I think he was referring to people.

Comment: @jakekimds moderators aren't people?

Comment: @santiago OK, that comment of mine was stupid. Let's ignore it.

Comment: @jakekimds it gave me a good laugh... and one wonders....

Comment: @KeyBored I wanted to just point out something very quickly - you said in the answer you kept posting that you were being restricted on your "Freedom of Speech" - have a look at this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7320

Comment: @Tim I don't know how your comment is supposed to help in answering this question.. anyway, thanx.

Comment: Downvoters, with no single comment about what's wrong with the question.. I cannot do much to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I feel like this is a bit of a setup, but...

> How can I communicate with this moderator to make sure of the reason for deletion ?

Ask. Here. In a post on meta, and in good faith.

I can't help but think you already knew that somehow...

Comment: I think today might be a new record for the most drama on SO ever. Even more so than the week of mass deletions a few years back.

Comment: That week would be awful hard to top.

Comment: Meh, every week is mass deletions at DevDoodle!

Comment: @Mysticial I think it may have been done.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for your answer.. but as a side comment.. I think it'd be easier to be able to comment on a deleted post instead of spamming the Meta with questions like "What's meant by ....?". Also, it's better for moderators to know if they were clear enough to the user.. I guess it won't harm as long as the post is deleted.